# Foreach increment in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a for loop which runs upto 50 times. In my codeigniter view I have

```
Year          Id
2015          1000001
2015          1000002
```

I have get database value using the following command

```
$data['get_data']=$this->get_data_model->getSeating();
```

I want to set the database value into sno, year, id in the view. But my database has only 2 columns.

```
    <?php $i=1; if(@$get_data)
      {
          foreach($get_data as $row):       
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="35"><?=$i?></td>
        <td align="left"><?=$row->year?></td>
        <td align="left"><?=$row->id?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      $i++;
      endforeach;
     }
```

This will shows only 2 rows. Because my database has two values only. But I need to allocate 50 rows even if the data is not in database.
e.g In my example i want to show in my view

Normally it shows like this

```
Sno    Year    ID
1       2015   100001
2       2015   100002
```

But I want to show like this

```
Sno    Year    ID
1       2015   100001
2       2015   100002
3
4
5
......
50
```

Comment: So, what is the issue? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I didn't get errors, but I want to show like the above view.

Comment: SO is not a coding service, try something and we will help you

Comment: Try with `for` loop instead of `foreach`.

Comment: typical use of `for` loop instead of `foreach` loop.. remember? ;)

Comment: did you try any for loop ?

Comment: for loop does not working here, inside the for loop it cant show the array values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic idea (you could put them in one loop if you like):

```
<?php 
$i=1; 
if(@$get_data) {
  foreach($get_data as $row):       
?>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" height="35"><?=$i?></td>
      <td align="left"><?=$row->year?></td>
      <td align="left"><?=$row->id?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    $i++;
  endforeach;
}
  for($j=$i; $j<51;$j++): 
?>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" height="35"><?=$j?></td>
      <td align="left"></td>
      <td align="left"></td>
    </tr>
<?php
  endfor;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about like this :

```
<?php for($x=1; $x<51; $x++){?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" height="35"><?=$x?></td>
        <td align="left"><?=$get_data[$x]->year?></td>
        <td align="left"><?=$get_data[$x]->id?></td>
    </tr><?php } ?>
```

Comment: will result in error if $get_data[$x] doesn't have a member set. Better check it before displaying.

Comment: Use `isset` function to preventing errors like that `isset($get_data[$x])`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a foreach loop you should use a for instead.
Something like this:

```
<?php
for(i=0;i <= 50;i++){
?>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="35"><?=$i?></td>
    <td align="left"><?=$row[$i]->year?></td>
    <td align="left"><?=$row[$i]->id?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Also you should check if $i is a valid index for $row:

```
isset($row[$i]) ? <td align="left"><?=$row[$i]->year?></td> : '';
```